# QHash of QVectors

Tags: qt, replace, constants, qhash, qvector

I have a `QHash<QString, QVector<float> > qhash` ,and trying to overwite the values in `QVector` as following:

```
void Coordinate::normalizeHashElements(QHash<QString, QVector<float> > qhash)
{
    string a = "Cluster";
    float new_value;
    float old_value;
    const char *b = a.c_str();
    float min = getMinHash(qhash);
    float max = getMaxHash(qhash);

    QHashIterator<QString, QVector<float> > i(qhash);
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            i.next();
            if(i.key().operator !=(b))
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<i.value().size(); j++)
                {
                    old_value = i.value().at(j);
                    new_value = (old_value - min)/(max-min)*(0.99-0.01) + 0.01;
                    i.value().replace(j, new_value);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I am getting an error on the `i.value().replace(j, new_value);` stroke saying following :

> C:\Qt\latest test\Prototype\Coordinate.cpp:266: error: passing 'const QVector' as 'this' argument of 'void QVector::replace(int, const T&) [with T = float]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

could anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you are attempting to use a non-`const` method on a `const` instance.  In this case, you are trying to call `QVector::replace` on a `const QVector`.  The main reason for this is because you are using `QHashIterator`, which only returns `const` references from [`QHashIterator::value()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhashiterator.html#value).

To fix this, you could use the STL-style iterator instead of the Java-style iterator on the `QHash`:

```
QString b("Cluster");
QHash<QString, QVector<float> >::iterator it;
for (it = qhash.begin(); it != qhash.end(); ++it)
{
   if (it.key() != b)
   {
      for (int j=0; i<it.value().size(); j++)
      {
         old_value = it.value().at(j);
         new_value = (old_value-min)/(max-min)*(0.99-0.01) + 0.01;
         it.value().replace(j, new_value);
      }
   }
}
```

You could also use [`QMutableHashIterator`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qmutablehashiterator.html) instead of `QHashIterator`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will try it out and leave feedback as soon as I am done.

Comment: @MikaelEgibyan  You're welcome.  Don't forget to accept answers that are helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer  :-)